# Rails resque scheduler run job at specific time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, resque-scheduler

I have this resque job that must run at **6 AM or 11 AM or 16 PM or 20 PM** o clock

or at least for example **6 am**

```
Resque.enqueue_at <what to put here>, SendSmsJob
```

How do I define specific time like that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it a `Time` and it'll run once that time is in the past, like so:

```
time = Time.new(2016, 6, 11, 20, 0)
Resque.enqueue_at time, SendSmsJob
```

Comment: Sorry I make you confused, I have edited my question, please check it out, thanks